# Calculate and save the value into switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I would like to calculate the sum of a variable that is located within a `switch`, which is incremented or decremented. The problem is that the variable's value is lost.

How do I save the value outside the switch?

JS:

```
 var count=0;
 switch (index) {
     case 0:
          $("#ris3").click(function () {
                count= count+5;
                document.getElementById("point").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = count;
          $("#ris1").click(function () {
                count= count- 1;
                document.getElementById("point").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = count;
          $("#ris2").click(function () {
                count= count- 1;
                document.getElementById("point").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = count;
          break;
     case 1:
          $("#ris4").click(function () {
                count= count+ 5;
                document.getElementById("point").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = count;
          $("#ris5").click(function () {
                count= count- 1;
                document.getElementById("point").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = count;
          $("#ris6").click(function () {
                count= count- 1;
                document.getElementById("point").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = count;
          break;
```

My Html:

```
<div id="point">
        //value point
        <p ></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the value lost ? Do you mean that is not put as `point` tag content as your code tries to do ?

Comment: document.getElementById("point").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = count : Is correct and function;But i want get value out from cicle Switch for calculate sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the variable as

```
window.count = 0;
```

However is desirable use some kind of namespace to get your code tiddy, for instance, you could create something like:

```
window.MyApp = {
    count = 0,
    // Added other global variables or methods for your app ///

}
```

So, you then can use then like:

```
MyApp.count += ...
```

Comment: can you provide some kind of error message ? or the code where you read the variable ?